# Handling variables from another class when saving from ArrayList to MySQL database

Tags: java, mysql, arraylist, prepared-statement

I am creating a Rpg game. Now, the game progress is saved to a txt file. I have created a database which will handle the save game instead. Currently I trying to connect the save game ArrayList to a MySQL table. All variables in the ArrayList are created in the Player class and inserted into the ArrayList. This is a snippet of the original code:

```
public void save(Player p) {
    clearData();

    ArrayList<Object> saveGame = new ArrayList<>();
    saveGame.add(p.getName());
```

Since I have rewritten the code to make it possible to store the data in the database, I am getting syntax errors (can't find symbol) when I am trying to insert "Player p" into the new code. I have try the insert it in the arguments, but I am getting syntax errors. How do I do this, now when the code look like this:

```
public void save(ArrayList<ArrayList<Object>> saveGame) {

    conn = Sqlprogress.ConnectDB();

    String query = " insert into GameProgress (Name, CurrLoc, Strength, Constitution, Dexterity, Hitpoints, Level, xP, xpToLvlUp, ArmorClass, setNrOfPotions, EqWeapon)"
            + " vaules (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";
    PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement(insert);
    clearData();

    for (ArrayList<Object> ar1 : saveGame) {
        ps.setString(1, p.getName());                  //Spelarens namn
        ps.setString(2, p.getCurrLoc());               //Spelarens position
        ps.setString(3, p.getStrength());              //Styrka
        ps.setString(4, p.getConstitution());          //Uthållighet
        ps.setString(5, p.getDexterity());             //Smidighet
        ps.setString(6, p.getHitpoints());             //Liv 
        ps.setString(7, p.getLevel());                 //Level
        ps.setString(8, p.xp());                 //Level
        ps.setString(9, p.getxPToLvlUp());             //Erfarenhetsgränsen för att gå upp i level
        ps.setString(10, p.getArmorClass());            //Armorclass
        ps.setString(11, p.getNrOfPotions());           //Antal hälsodrycker
        ps.setString(12, p.getEqWeapon().getName());    //Utrustat vapen (namnet på vapnet sparas)

        //Lägger till allt i inventariet i listan, det är namnen på föremålen sparas
        //Lägger till allt i inventariet i listan, det är namnen på föremålen sparas
        for (Object element : p.getInventory()) {
            if (element instanceof Weapon) {
                saveGame.add(((Weapon) element).getName());
            } else if (element instanceof Item) {
                saveGame.add(((Item) element).getName());
            } else if (element instanceof Armor) {
                saveGame.add(((Armor) element).getName());
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: "I am getting syntax errors" and you don't think those syntax errors are worth sharing?

Comment: So sorry I forgot to mention it. I have updated the question. I am getting this error: "can't find symbol".

Comment: [How do I ask questions here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seems to have corrected all the errors associated with the `query` and the `PreparedStatement`.

If you are saying `symbols cannot be found` then, I suggest you look carefully at your `Player p`, if `p` is really intialized properly before passing it to any method (For example the `save()` method). For proper initialization , mean something like `Player p = new Player();`.

Okay then if that is done, and error still prevails, then check if the `Player` Class has the following methods that you are calling on its instance `p`(as in `p.getName()`).

If Still prevails, check if `Player` Class is actually imported if it is from a different package or else where.

Generally, I suggest you try to find out some of the possible causes of problem(`Can't find symbol`) and the various ways to combat it.
So Suggest to you [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25706216/what-does-a-cannot-find-symbol-compilation-error-mean) and [here too](http://java.about.com/od/cerrmsg/g/Definition-Cannot-Find-Symbol.htm), to figure out what may possibly be causing the error and how to fix it.

Comment: Hello! Player P = new Player solved the issue! Thank you Young Millie and everyone else who helped me!

Comment: If `Player P =new Player();` helped you solved it,  then why mark @MrLY's answer as best answer when `Player P =new Player();`  can only   be found in my answer.  Give to Caezar what belongs to Caezar. Appreciate my effort, Thank you

Comment: I am sorry... I am thankful to you both.. I clicked on you both, apparently it didn't work out as planned. But yes, you helped me with the code I do appreciate your effort Young Millie! And you did solve the problem I asked for. Thanks!